# Upload sites files and folders via ftp bash

Tags: bash, file, ftp, upload, directory

I need a script to upload files of sites with directories to hosting via ftp.
I try to create a script, but it doesn't work. NO files are on the server. Can you help me, please?

My script

```
#!/bin/bash  
HOST='ip_address'
USER='user'
PASSWD='password'
SERVER_FOLDER='/site'
cd /local_folder_with_sites_files
ftp -in <<END_SCRIPT
open $HOST
user $USER $PASSWD
cd $SERVER_FOLDER
mput -r *
close
bye
END_SCRIPT
echo "Upload complete"
exit 0
```

Output:

```
directory: not a plain file.
Permission denied.
Passive mode refused.
```

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 Panel: VestaCP

But when i upload files via filezilla, uploads is complete.

If anybody has a script which uploads files and folders via ftp, please, show me for example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? What error you are getting? Also explain more about environment like operating system, version etc.

Comment: *"Doesn't work for me"* doesn't work for us as a problem description. What is the problem? Do you get any errors? Or is the behavior different to what you expect?